# GEKKO dynamic optimisation with lagged variable in objective

Tags: optimization, dynamic, lag, gekko

I am trying to optimise the following objective function using GEKKO:

`Objective = sum[(Y(t)/Y(t-1)) - G(t)]^2`

where the objective function is summed over time t = 0 to 10.
Y(t) is the choice/control variable at time period t and G(t) is value given for teach time period t. The constraints are: (1) Y(0) = 5.64 (2) Y(10)= 3.

I am very new to optimisation in python. And the following code probably has many errors. Can someone please help? Thank you.

```py
#Problem 2
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

#initialize 
m= GEKKO()

#time points (say we have 10 time points)
nt= 10
m.time = np.linspace (0,1,nt)

#variables (say initial value of y at t=0 is given as 5.64)
y_init = np.array([5.64]*nt)
yo = [ m.Var ( value = y_init [ i ] ) for i in range ( nt ) ]

#parameter
g_init=np.array([-0.025751073, -0.026431718, -0.027149321, -0.025581395, \
                 -0.026252983, -0.022058824, -0.020050125, -0.015345269, \
                 -0.015584416, -0.01055409])
g =[ m.Param ( value = gs_init [ i ] ) for i in range ( nt ) ]

#Equations
a1=5.64
a2=3.1
m.Equation(yo[0]==a1)
m.Equation(yo[9]==a2)

#Objective Function 
m.Obj(sum(((yo[i] /yo[i-1]) - g[i] )**2 ) for i in range(nt-1))

#set global options
m.options.IMODE =6
m.solve(disp=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

A dynamic optimization mode (`IMODE=6`) isn't needed because there are no differential equations. Here is a modified solution script with `IMODE=3`. I added a lower bound (`lb=1e-5`), otherwise the solver fails to find a solution because of divide-by-zero in the objective function.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m= GEKKO()
nt= 10
a1=5.64; a2=3.1
yo = m.Array(m.Var,nt,value=a1,lb=1e-5)

gi=[-0.025751073, -0.026431718, -0.027149321, -0.025581395, \
    -0.026252983, -0.022058824, -0.020050125, -0.015345269, \
    -0.015584416, -0.01055409]
g = [m.Param(value=gi[i]) for i in range (nt)]
m.Equation(yo[0]==a1)
m.Equation(yo[9]==a2)
for i in range(nt-1):
    m.Minimize(((yo[i]/yo[i-1])-g[i])**2)
m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(disp=True)

print(yo)
```

It produces the solution:

```
[[5.64] [5.267947462] [4.9219842299] [3.8147730229] [0.30626159246]
 [0.023821036642] [0.0018246461089] [0.00013501474087] [1e-05] [3.1]]
```

I recommend checking the objective function because the `gi` values suggest that the optimal `yo` solution should progressively get smaller and alternate between positive and negative to have a negative ratio.